# AWS target group is unhealthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, server

I’m in trouble with aws ALB setting.

When I set target group to listen 80 port with path “/“ it returns unhealthy.

My apache web server is running, and I make index.html file on path “/var/lib/www/html”.

But when I start my tomcat service with port 8080 it works. It returns healthy.

I don’t know why.. anyone have answer for this?

Comment: If you app is listening on port 8080, your target group should also use 8080.

Comment: @Marcin, my apache httpd server listening on port 80. But not healthy...

Comment: You need to clarify your architecture. What `tomcat service` has to do with your httpd server?